# How can I draw a pattern inside a path on a canvas in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image, flutter-canvas

I want to draw crossing diagonal lines inside a path on a canvas in Flutter.

Right now I've sort of got it working by loading an image asset into a `ui.Image` and then using a `CustomPainter` with an `ImageShader` to draw it on the canvas. It works, but it requires that I create an image asset for each pair of line colors (it's not only red/black).

```
Future<ui.Image> _loadAssetImage(int number) {
  Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();

  AssetImage('assets/pngs/pattern_$number.png')
    .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
    .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall){
      ui.Image img;
      img = image.image;
      completer.complete(img);
    })
  );

  return completer.future;
}

ui.Image myImage = await _loadAssetImage(1);
```

and then

```
          canvas.drawPath(path, Paint()
            ..shader = ImageShader(myImage, TileMode.repeated, TileMode.repeated, Matrix4.identity().scaled(0.2).storage)
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
          );

          canvas.drawPath(path, Paint()
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
            ..strokeJoin= StrokeJoin.round
            ..strokeCap= StrokeCap.round
            ..color = Colors.black
            ..strokeWidth = 1
          );
```

However, I'm interested to know if there is a more efficient way to do this than loading and drawing asset images. It should be easy - after all it's really just repeating lines - but I can't figure out how to draw them and clip them to the path.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is clipping an option? E.g. draw the full rectangular background with any painter you want, then add some sort of clipping to remove the areas you don't want? https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/08/flutter-draw-custom-shaps-clip-path.html

Comment: @SebastianRoth I need to draw it on a canvas, and there are many other things being drawn on the canvas as well, so I can't just clip it to the path easily. I would somehow need to draw it on a separate image I guess, and then use that image in the same way I'm using the asset image. Or if there is a way to copy one canvas onto another, that might be an option, but I haven't found any such solutions when searching.

Answer (score 0):

Just clipping path and draw lines in path bounds:

```
        var b = path.getBounds();

        FCanvas.save();
        FCanvas.clipPath(path);

        for (int i = step; i < b.width; i = i + step)
          FCanvas.drawLine(Offset(b.left + i, b.top), Offset(b.left + i, b.bottom), getPenPaint());

        for (int i = step; i < b.height; i = i + step)
          FCanvas.drawLine(Offset(b.left, b.top + i), Offset(b.right, b.top + i), getPenPaint());


        FCanvas.restore();
```